# Force at end of pivot beam, based on total mass and CG?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

A handle lever need to be balanced so it does not move by gravity or vertical acceleration. This handle moves ±90∘ from center (top position). Supported by ball bearing in center. The unit can barely be balanced by the heavy and expensive copper counterweight as shown, it can easily be balanced by using a lead or tungsten counterweight, but I don't want to use either of those materials... Apart from the counterweight everything (incl. the cap-screw) is aluminum. How to calculate the force of gravity (F) at 90∘, to determine if it is within acceptable limit?
[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to make the center of mass at the pivot point.  What would knowing that force tell you?

Comment: Yes I know, but that reqires a big (thick) copperweight and a deep pocket in the hub to make room for that counterweight. I want to keep all dimensions and the mass of the counterwight to a minimum. I'm prepared to accept CM a bit off the pivot point. At what distance does it start to become a problem?, I want the right haptic feel when moving the lever. The lever is driving a light load, a potensiometer or optical sensor, 5-10N at the grip (adjusted by a friction brake)... The added force of gravity at the extremes of travel should be no more than 1/4 of that.

Comment: Problem solved (sort of). The customer just called and says he does not want such a "light" lever as originally specified.
He now wants a force of about 50-100N on the grip, and that is 10 times more than the out-of-balance force, so that wont
even be noticable. No counterweight needed!